# iOS App communicating with PC program and vice versa

Tags: ios, windows, bluetooth, wifi

Hi I’m trying to make a app that will communicate with a program on a PC (windows 7) and vice versa, and was wondering what the best way to do this. (I would prefer using C++ for the program on PC)

What I’m basically looking for them to do is on the iOS Device, I press a button in the app and it just sends a 1, 2, or 3 to the program and the program reads this number and then executes something based on this number. So “button 1” was pressed “command 1” was executed.

Comment: tons of ways to do this so you need to narrow down your choices, bonjour is a wifi option, webserver with something like php playing middle man could be another option but look into how bonjour works for starters. There are some free open source apps I've tried that have used bonjour to control my macs mouse from iPhone.

Comment: I didn’t think that it worked that well on PC?

Comment: how would you prefer to communicate local wifi or internet?

Comment: I’m aiming for local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then basically you're going to look up sockets programming, for windows here is a start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx and for ios here is the always fun Apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/(null)-SW8 though with a little research im sure someone out there has made a quick framework or example that can get your applications connected faster if you want past the network stuff asap.